# Angular2/4 in Safari browser

Tags: angular, safari, polyfills

We are trying to run an application in Safari browser(Application is running fine in IE11,Chrome and Mozilla) we are getting following error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' (in vendo.bundel.js)
logo.jsGET http://localhost:4200/iojs/latest/logo.js 404 (Not Found)

We had already installed intl and following setting are available in polyfill.ts

// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';

Safari version is 5.1.7 and OS is window 7(64 bit).

Comment: instead of manually set up everything - us following angualr framework: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter

Comment: Can you please let us know how?

Comment: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter#quick-start - study documentation

Comment: project is setup in same way as specified, and running perfectly fine on IE Chrome.Only issue with Safari

Comment: strange - its looks like safri not support es6 'const' keyword you need some polyfil... however angular-starter works in safari... so may be not try to invent the wheel a second time ?

Comment: more strange our target is es5 )::compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163519/discussion-between-user3886602-and-kamil-kielczewski).

Comment: i write comment on chat